# An answer is deleted from my question

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22845102/3330969) yesterday and got an answer, but now I can't see it. It's like nobody ever answered. Can someone tell me why this has happened and what can I do for it? It was such a helpful answer.

Comment: Dunno why you were downvoted but, as a suggestion, you should make it as easy as possible for people to help you. So, when you say "I asked a question yesterday", you should *link to that question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the answer deleted it. Unless you have 10k reputation you won't be able to see deleted answers.

You are always allowed to delete your own answers, except when it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

I can only see one question on your account (at the time of writing).
It had one answer, but it was deleted by its owner. Deleted questions and answers are only visible to folks with at least 10K reputation, which you don't have at the moment. That is why you can't see the answer.

Comment: He had a reason to delete this answer. Not sure if bringing it back in here is a good idea.

Comment: @Szymon heh, that's why I for one edit my self-deleted answers and add an explanation: [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt8TC.png "screen shot"), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uxtsB.png "screen shot"), [3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/234089/31260 "10K link to Programmers")

Comment: In my humble opinion, I think he thought that it was not the real solution, instead just only a hint to pinpoint the problem, and thus he deleted it. But well... I can only guess.

Comment: @Szymon: I was not sure of it, but reading the comments thread once again, I think you're right. I've updated my answer now.

Comment: @gnat: That's really a good practice. I've done that for a few of my self-deleted answers, too. It's not always required though :)